# Why does God speak to David using both second and third-person in 2 Samuel 7:12-16?

Tags: 2-samuel

2 Samuel 7:12-16 (NIV) says,

> 12 When your days are over and you rest with your ancestors, I will raise up your offspring to succeed you, your own flesh and blood, and I will establish his kingdom. 13 He is the one who will build a house for my Name, and I will establish the throne of his kingdom forever. 14 I will be his father, and he will be my son. When he does wrong, I will punish him with a rod wielded by men, with floggings inflicted by human hands. 15 But my love will never be taken away from him, as I took it away from Saul, whom I removed from before you. 16 Your house and your kingdom will endure forever before me; your throne will be established forever.’”

In this speech, God speaks to David using both second and third-person points of view. Beginning from verse 12, God uses the second-person point of view (*'you'* and *'your'*), then transitions to third-person near the end of verse 12 to 15a (*'he'*, *'him'*, and *'his'*), and finally with second-person again in 15b and 16. Why?

Answer (score 5):

The third-person pronouns are directed toward David's *offspring* (per NIV), as in:

> I will raise up **your offspring** to succeed you, your own flesh and
> blood, and I will establish his kingdom.

That "offspring," of course, can represent the Messiah.

In the KJV it reads:

> And when thy days be fulfilled, and thou shalt sleep with thy fathers,
> I will set up **thy seed** after thee, which shall proceed out of thy
> bowels, and I will establish his kingdom. (2 Samuel 7:12, KJV)

This is the same "seed" which was first promised in Genesis 3:15.

> And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed
> and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his
> heel. (Genesis 3:15, KJV)

But it ALSO, in a more immediate and literal sense, speaks of David's son *Solomon* who was to build "Solomon's Temple" which would help to establish God's name in Israel.

Thus, the text can have a dual meaning, depending on which layer of significance one chooses to see.

Answer (score 3):

2 Samuel 7:

> 12 When your [David] days are over and you [D] rest with your [D] ancestors, I will raise up your [D] offspring to succeed you [D], your [D] own flesh and blood, and I will establish his [Solomon] kingdom. 13 He [S] is the one who will build a house for my Name, and I will establish the throne of his [S] kingdom forever. 14 I will be his father, and he [S] will be my son. When he [S] does wrong, I will punish him  [S] with a rod wielded by men, with floggings inflicted by human hands. 15 But my love will never be taken away from him [S], as I took it away from Saul, whom I removed from before you. 16 Your [D] house and your kingdom will endure forever before me; your [D] throne will be established forever.’”

The second-person consistently refers to David. The third-person consistently refers to Solomon.

Answer (score 0):

The whole ISR part reads as follows:
“When your days are filled and you rest with your fathers, I (God) shall raise up your seed (DNA and offspring) after you, who comes from your inward parts, and shall establish his (god) reign.

> 13 “He (the seed/DNA)/offspring) does build a house for My Name (God), and I (God) shall establish the throne of his (the seed,/DNA/offspring) reign forever.
>
> 14 “I (God) am to be his (the seed, DNA/offspring) Father, and he is My son. If he does perversely (not mate correctly?), I shall reprove him (the seed,/DNA/offspring) with *the rod of men (measuring tool?) and with the blows of the sons of men* (the seed/DNA/offspring that **was ruler** now will be ruled and beaten down).
>
> 15 “But My kindness does not turn aside from him (the later generations coming from David/the seed/DNA/offspring), as I turned it aside from Sha’ul, whom I removed from before you (David, not the seed/not the DNA, not the offspring).
>
> 16 “And your (David) house and your reign are to be steadfast forever before (in the future) you – your throne is established forever.” ’ ”
>
> 17 According to all these words and according to all this vision, **so Nathan spoke to Dawiḏ.**